# Elasticsearch Grails Plugin: How to index files?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there a possibility to *upload and index* files via the elasticsearch grails plugin?

The https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments plugin is installed in my elasticsearch server.

The Elasticsearch grails documentation http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/ does not mention a mapping for files.

A domain class could perhaps look like this:

```
class Document {
     String filecontent

     static searchable = {
       only = ["filecontent"]
       filecontent attachment:true
      }
}
```

where *filecontent* is the base64 encoded file.
Actually this works, but I cannot get the highlighting working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to highlight uploaded content with the standard index mapping from elasticsearch-grails-plugin.

I explained a workaround here: https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

Well elastic search plugin do that for you as long as you create or update any domain instance with `static search` field.

But if you want to do it forcefully, you can inject the bean `elasticSearchService` in a temporary action or so and call the `index()` method on it.

That will index your instances.

http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/ref/ElasticSearchService/index.html

Comment: Yes, I know. But currently my problem is to configure the index to highlight content that was indexed using the mapper-attachments-plugin